# cambiar la posición de un DockWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

trabajo con **Qgis**, tengo un pequeño `DockWidget` hecho en **python 2.7** metido en `LeftDockWidgetArea` el caso es que al iniciar Qgis se me pone debajo de otro panel, ¿cómo puedo cambiar la posición de mi `DockWidget`?

El código que tengo es :

```
self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.search_plus.dlg)
```

Como veis esto me lo añade, pero me lo añade el ultimo del área, ¿cómo lo pongo el primero?